# Search Fullname, in two fields firstname, lastname rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm working a search box for my application i have two fields firstname and lastname. I create a full_name method for them.

Profile model:

```
def full_name
"#{self.firstname} #{self.lastname}"
end
```

and this is my method for search

```
def self.search_by_full_name(search)
where("(fisrtname || lastname) LIKE :q", :q => "%#{search}%")
end
```

Profile Controller:

```
def index
 if params[:search]
  @profile = Profile.search_by_full_name(params[:search])
  else
  @profile = Profile.all
end
```

end

Comment: is there any news on this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Do this simple trick**

```
   def self.search_by_full_name(search)
   @names = search.split(" ")
   where("first_name LIKE ? AND last_name LIKE ?", "%#{@names[0]}","%#{@names[1]}" )
end
```

Comment: it works but if i search for lastname it outputs nill

Comment: See my answer again. This is only for full name search if you are using both then you can use OR instead of AND in sql

Comment: thanks for the reply if i use or they work fine but if i give lastname he give me all Profile

Comment: This might be the problem that when you only send lastname there is nill in @names[1] and value seats in @name[0] you can solve it manually

Comment: @wiwit is there any news on this?

Comment: You can use conditional in case you are searching using only one field

Answer (score 18):

You can do it as

```
where("CONCAT_WS(' ', first_name, last_name) LIKE ?", "%#{query}%")
```

or you can create a scope

```
scope :search_by_full_name ->(query) { where("CONCAT_WS(' ', first_name, last_name) LIKE ?", "%#{query}%") }
```

Comment: SQLite3::SQLException: no such function: CONCAT_WS: SELECT "profiles".* FROM "profiles" WHERE (CONCAT_WS(' ', firstname, lastname) LIKE '%Jesse Castro%')

Comment: SQLite is not recommended to use with rails. Please use MYSQL or Postgres

Answer (score 2):

I was stuck with the same problem, So, In order to cover every case scenario.

**The best solution for this situation is below**

```
where("CONCAT(first_name,' ',last_name) iLIKE ? OR CONCAT(last_name,' ',first_name ) iLIKE ?", "%#{query}%", "%#{query}%")
```

**P.S.** Make sure you apply the ***squish*** method on your query first
`query = search.squish`

Answer (score 0):

My suggestions and its closer to what you have

```
def self.search_by_full_name(search)
    where("fisrtname LIKE :search OR lastname LIKE :search", search: "%#{search}%")
end
```

This works for me well. i use sqlite

Comment: did you try to search for lastname only?

Answer (score 0):

Your query is slightly wrong:

```
def self.search_by_full_name(search)
  where("firstname like :search OR lastname like :search", search: "%#{search}%")
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this

```
User.where("first_name||' '||last_name ilike :name", :name => "%first_name last_name%")
```

Comment: There isn't any `User` on which call the where method

Comment: User is refer to any AR model